# How to assign values to a slice in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have to reassign a reassign a column value for specific rows based on state. The data frame I am working with has only two columns, SET VALUE and AMOUNT, with STATE being in the index. I need to change the value of SET VALUE to 'YES' for the 3 customers with the highest value in the AMOUNT column for each state. How can I do this in the pandas framework?

I have attempted to use a for loop on the state in the index and then sort by AMOUNT column values and assign 'YES' to the first three rows in the SET VALUE column.

```
for state in trial.index:
    trial[trial.index == state].sort_values('AMOUNT', ascending = False)['SET VALUE'].iloc[0:3] = 'YES'
    print(trial[trial.index == state])
```

I am expecting the print portion of this loop to include 3 'YES' values but instead all I get are 'NO' values (the default for the column). It is unclear to me why this is happening.

Comment: `trial[...].sort_values(...)` doesn't operate in-place. It creates a new dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against repeated index for various reasons. This case being one, as it is harder for you to update the rows. Here's what I would do:

```
# make STATE a column, and index continuous numbers
df = df.reset_index()

# get the actual indexes of the largest amounts
idx = df.groupby('STATE').AMOUNT.nlargest(3).index.get_level_values(1)

# update
df.loc[idx, 'SET_VALUE'] = 'YES'
```